# Should I be concerned with the error xauth: /home/user/.serverauth.535 does not exist?

Tags: fedora, xauth

I installed a minimal Fedora system and have built it up to getting X running with Xmonad as my window manager. I can `startx` fine and so far I don't see any issues with my current setup while in X. When I leave X, the first line I see is

```
xauth: /home/user/.serverauth.535 does not exist
```

What can I do to remedy this error? I check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` and I don't find any lines with `(EE)` so I don't think there is an error.

FYI, I did not `yum group install "X Window System"` but I only installed all the `Mandatory Packages` and some select `Default Packages` in the group. Could this be causing the `xauth` error?

Answer (score 1):

The `.serverauth.XXXX` gets created and/or used by some startx scripts. When you don't use xauth you can disable it by changing `enable_xauth=1` to `enable_xauth=0` in the startx script.